# Exercise with error function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, error-function

Be  $g(x)=x^3-3x+1$ I have to draw the graph of $f(x)=g(4\int_0^x e^{-y^2}dy)$

Because materially calculate the integral is impossible (this is what I understand), I thought I could simply replace the integral in the first expression of g(x) and then derive with respect to x this new expression of g until order 3. However I don't know if derivation is correct, because when I derived I considered the integral like his derivative was the expression that appears in the integral.

At the third order of derivation I obtain
$$g'''\left (4\int_0^x e^{-y^2}dy\right )=f'''(x)=6$$

And then I integrate f'''(x) three times in order to get f(x)

Something seems to be wrong, probably the entire procedure.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please use MathJax for mathematical equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Did you remember to use the chain rule?

Comment: Just put one 'inside' the other and leaves the hard work to the computer.